# Rules for inflecting Tibetan nouns and verbs?

Tags: reference-request, inflection, tibetan

The internet is scarce in Tibetan grammar, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Lhasa_Tibetan_grammar) being the best I can find. It says there are 6 noun cases, and gives the pattern for inflecting the base noun, it seems. Is that all that is required for inflecting nouns?

What about verbs? I haven't found much on verbs except for [this Tibetan verb db](https://github.com/tibetan-nlp/tibetan-verbs-database/blob/ca6ba75066aa8cfd53631d0f3ad0350e026b8b4e/db.csv), not sure what it represents. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lhasa_Tibetan#Verbal_system) suggests there are 12 forms per verb, is that correct?

If there is not a free web resource explaining the patterns for verb and noun inflection, what is a standard reference book which could be purchased in English? If it can be explained concisely, or at least outlined, please add that as well. If it's too complex, then a great book resource would be useful.

*One thing I am wondering that led to this question is, can the inflections be automatically generated if you knew all the rules? That is, are the few and predictable rules, or is it like English where it is a case-by-case situation? Tangent question. If it's predictable, I would like to then automate their construction with code. I can do that part :) at least, if it's predictable.*

Comment: In general, *if you know **all** the rules* (which no one does), then yes, all you need to do is follow them, just like native speakers do. But there are different accounts, by different linguists with different ideas at different times for different purposes, so there can't be any "all the rules". Most likely there are a lot of exceptions for inflections, and derivations are always unpredictable; but the paradigms should do the job most of the time. Plus, learning when one uses which inflection and what they mean is not always simple. Texts are your friend here.

Comment: @Lance Do you have a good go-to Tibetan grammar? Just because verbal "inflection" and final particles bleed into each other _a lot_ in Tibetan grammar, and so it's very much a matter of definition. Add the concepts of _aspect_ and _evidentiality_, and you get a system which is difficult to simply "tabulate".